# Area target in AR Foundation

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am trying to develop an AR application in unity using AR Foundation. My intention is to track a wide area like a house (something like this https://youtu.be/rViYSIn-NOg) and I have seen that in Vuforia there is a Target Area. Is there something equivalent in AR foundation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, updated to Q1 2021, there's few tools out there but they're mostly small companies specifically focus on indoor AR navigation using their own area target tool like in Vuforia, but Vuforia is so powerful and so ahead of others in AR area target contents creation.

You can easily achieve it by an iPad Pro 2020 (with LiDAR), install the iOS Vuforia Area Target creator app and scan the space and export it into Unity, then you easily add those augmented objects around it, test the result in editor, build an app and that's it. You can achieve it within 30 minutes.

Your journey starts here:

https://library.vuforia.com/features/environments/area-targets.html

If you want very-precise scanned area data (buy this "cheapest" professional LiDAR camera in market - Matterport Pro 2 3D Camera). It has all the tutorial works with vuforia and to Unity and it is as easy as new-born baby can do it straightaway.

I've tried Unity MARS, ARKit and ARFoundation, none of them are close to what Vuforia is offering to date in the sense of contents creation ease.